# Bind Liquid Template Filter to a Context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, liquid

I would like to be able to bind a Rails Liquid Template filter to a context.

For example, say I have a filter called 'asset_url' that I would like to use as follows:

{{ 'style.css' | asset_url }}

I would like the asset_url filter to be able to lookup the key 'style.css' on a per user-account basis like so:

https://somewhere.com/users/10/assets/style.css

Notice that I need to retrieve the asset_url for user_id=10.

Is there a way for me to bind/initialize an arbitrary context to a Liquid filter?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Trying to do the same thing myself this morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the **@context** variable in your filter, specifically the **@context.registers** hash.

Pass your user into the registers hash:

```
@user = User.first

@template = Liquid::Template.parse("{{ 'style.css' | asset_url }}")
@template.render({}, registers: { user: @user })
```

In your filter:

```
module MyAssetFilter
  def asset_url(value)
    # @context.registers[:user] is available for use here

    if asset = @context.registers[:user].assets.find_by(filename: value)
      asset.filename
      # etc...
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.